# Computing integral of a line plot in R

Tags: r, plot, integral

I have two positive-valued vectors x,y of the same length in R. Using plot(x, y, "l",...), gives me a continuous line plot in 2 dimensions out of my finite vectors x and y. Is there a way to compute a definite integral over some range of this line plot in R?

edit1: I've looked into the integrate function in R. I'm not sure however how to make a function out of two vectors to pass to it, as my vectors are both finite.

edit2: For some more background, The length of x and y ~ 10,000. I've written a function to find periods, [xi, xj], of abnormalities in the data I'm observing. For each of these abnormalities, I've used plot to see what's going on in these snippets of my data. Now i need to compute statistics concerning the values of the integrals in these abnormal periods, so I'm trying to get as accurate as a number as possible to match with my graphs. X is a time variable, and I've taken very fine intervals of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `approxfun` function will take 2 vectors and return a function that gives the linear interpolation between the points.  This can then be passed to functions like `integrate`.  The `splinefun` function will also do interpolation, but based on a spline rather than piecewise linear.

In the piecewise linear case the integral will just be the sum of the trapezoids, it may be faster/simpler to just sum the areas of the trapezoids (the width, difference in x's

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will try this out. Is the interpolation used by approxfun similar to the interpolation that plot() uses under the hood? Just want to make sure their aren't discrepancies between my plots and the results of using approxfun.

Comment: @mt88, both use linear interpolation (if the x's are ordered) and it will give the same results (well pretty close, integrate chooses where to interpolate at and could cut a corner, but the difference will be small).

Answer (score 5):

You can do the integration with `integrate()`. To create a function out of your vectors `x` and `y`, you need to interpolate between the values. `approxfun()` does exactly that.

`integrate` takes a function and two bounds.

`approxfun` takes two vectors `x` and `y` just like those you have.

So my solution would be :

```
integrate(approxfun(x,y), range(x)[1], range(x)[2])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I saw that online, but wasn't sure how to make a function out of two vectors in R. care to elaborate?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want. You want to compute the integral of the function that maps each element of `x` to the corresponding element of `y`?

Comment: Correct. The twist is, x and y are finite, like x = c(1, 3, 9, 7, 12, 15) and y = c(2, 17, 99, 21, 33, 16). So they don't together form a continuous function.

Comment: Then isn't your integral just the sum of y?

Comment: I wouldn't think so. If I had x = c(1, 1.1, 1000) and y = c(0, 50, 50), I doubt my integral by the line created by R under plot would be 100?

Comment: Ok, so you need to interpolate between your values. The `approx` function can do that. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the continued help. Is approxfun simalair to the interpolation that plot uses under the hood. I'm try to avoid discrepancies between my calculations and plots.

Answer (score 1):

I landed here much later. But for future visitors, 
here is some code for the suggestion from
Greg Snow's answer, for piece-wise linear functions:

```
line_integral <- function(x, y) {
dx <- diff(x)
  end <- length(y)
  my <- (y[1:(end - 1)] + y[2:end]) / 2
  sum(dx *my)
} 

# example
x <- c(0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6)
y <- c(0, 0, 1,-2,-1, 0, 0)
plot(x,y,"l")
line_integral(x,y)
```

Comment: Your solution is in principle correct, but the example is a bit unlucky, because your vectors `x` and `y` do not define a function: it is not well-defined for `x = 5`. This means that for your example, the function will not be well approximated using `approxfun`. `f <- approxfun(x, y)` leads to `f(5) = -0.5`, which is probably not what you intended.

Comment: I actually did it on purpose: mt88was tryingg to get the integral of a piecewise-linear graph (x,y), whichever functions it comes from. (In this case it could come from a non continuous function...except for the vertical part)

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for!